# Fazer botão desaparecer

Tags: javascript

Tenho um código que quando clica no botão desativar, pede o motivo que você está desativando a foto. Quando confirma esse motivo, ele deveria desaparecer o botão que está do lado. Tenho um código com javascript para fazer toda a parte de pedir o motivo da desativação da foto, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer o botão ao lado desaparecer.

Esse é o código em javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.desativar', function(){
  var t = $(this);
  $.SmartMessageBox({
    title : "<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_title"); ?>",
    content : "<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_d"); ?>",
    buttons : "[<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_n"); ?>][<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_y"); ?>]",
    input : "text",
    inputValue: "",
    placeholder : "<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_place"); ?>"
  }, function(ButtonPress, Value) {
    if(ButtonPress == "<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_n"); ?>"){
      return 0;
    }else{
      if(Value == ""){
        notifica('<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_title"); ?>', '<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_inpmpt"); ?>', 4000);
      }else{
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Controller/Funcao/" + $(t).attr('id') + "/0",
          data: {justificativa: Value},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(r) {
            if(r) {
              $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.msg_des').show();

              $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.graf_lau').css('display','none');
              $(t).parent().parent().next().find('blockquote > .graf_lau').css('display','block');
              $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.img_lau_d').show();
              $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.img_lau_a').css('display','none');
              $(t).removeClass('desabilitar btn-danger');
              $(t).addClass('habilitar btn-success');
              $(t).empty();
              $(t).append('<span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span><?= $this->lang->line("view_inflaud_iten_btn_h"); ?>');
            } else {
              notifica('<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_title"); ?>', '<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_d"); ?>', 4000);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Pode ser feito assim `document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display="none";
` apenas troque `myBtn` pelo `id` do seu button

Comment: detalhe, este `.css('display','none');`  e a mesma coisa só que em `jquery` provavelmente o seu seletor não esta sendo encontrado.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues esse código que me mandou funcionou, muito obrigada inclusive, porém esse botão repete, se eu chamar ele pelo id só vai funcionar pela primeira vez.

Comment: Como esse botão se repete, ao clicar em desativar irá "desaparecer" todos os botões ou apenas um?

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML dos dois botões?

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser feito de uma maneira simples, usando o seletor $ do jQuery.

Para ocultar o elemento:

```
$("#seuBotao").hide();
```

Para mostrar o elemento:

```
$("#seuBotao").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Também é possível fazer isso utilizando o AngularJS, usando o **ng-if** ou o **ng-show**.

Exemplo simples:

```
<div ng-if="var == true">Isso vai aparecer quando a variavel "var" for verdadeira</div>
```

Para usar o ng-show, basta substituir o **ng-if por ng-show**. A diferença é que o show apenas esconde/mostra, e o if carrega o elemento de novo.